# scale canvas image using translate() and scale() but get x and y coordinates same as original canvas image using javascript

Tags: html, html5-canvas

after double click on canvas image on initial scale  of 1.08 it will give x and y which is not match after i scaled canvas image. i want same x and y even canvas is scaled. Even after scaled canvas i need same or drag canvas, i need same x and y without change. because i want to calculate distance between 2 points drawn on canvas, so if i calculate distance between two points without zoom(after click on plus button) and after zoom both are different for same area of canvas image. why?

html

```
<input type="button" id="plus" value="+">
<input type="button" id="minus" value="-">    
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

javascript

```
<script>
function draw(scale, translatePos){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // clear canvas
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.save();
    context.translate(translatePos.x, translatePos.y);
    context.scale(scale, scale);
    t = scale ;
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width,    img.height,     // source rectangle
                   0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // destination rectangle;


    context.restore();
}

var initialize = (function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

    var translatePos = {
        x: canvas.width/10,
        y: canvas.height/10 
    };

    var scale = 1.0;
    var scaleMultiplier = 0.92;
    var startDragOffset = {};
    var mouseDown = false;
    var t = 1.0;


    img = new Image();
    img.src = 'http://irlen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/world-map-large.png';

    // add button event listeners
    document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function(){
        scale /= scaleMultiplier;
        draw(scale, translatePos);
    }, false);

    document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function(){
        scale *= scaleMultiplier;
        draw(scale, translatePos);
    }, false);
 canvas.addEventListener("dblclick", function(evt){


        alert(evt.clientX / t +' '+evt.clientY);

    });
    // add event listeners to handle screen drag
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt){
        mouseDown = true;
        startDragOffset.x = evt.clientX - translatePos.x;
        startDragOffset.y = evt.clientY - translatePos.y;
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(evt){
        mouseDown = false;
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt){
        mouseDown = false;
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt){
        mouseDown = false;
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt){
        if (mouseDown) {
            translatePos.x = evt.clientX - startDragOffset.x;
            translatePos.y = evt.clientY - startDragOffset.y;
            draw(scale, translatePos);
        }
    });

    draw(scale, translatePos);
}());
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide working link... it will easy to provide solution on it.

Comment: according to image canvas zoom in zoom out, drawn line also redraw at same position that i drawn before zoom in. i want solution but i cant find becuase lineTo(x,y): x and y corredinates will change every time after zoom in zoom out . which method i need to implement to get perfect solution?

Comment: I have updated the link you can check there and let me know if you have any issue in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per given code and provided Link I could see you just need to divid the current distance with latest scale factor.

```
new_measure = getDistance(x1,x2,y1,y2) / scaleFactor;
```

Comment: you can maintain (store) all lines (start & end points)  in an array. Every time you redraw the canvas just redraw draw lines using that array and use scaleFactor accordingly.

Comment: if i remove context.translate(translatePos.x, translatePos.y) from draw(scale, translatePos) function then it will give me exact. but i also want drag on canvas image and its possible with context.translate(translatePos.x, translatePos.y). so with this i cant get exact new_x1. can you suggest me?

Comment: even after drag image i want all lines back to image at same position but i cant get it.

Comment: create a link for that with current version of your code. I will make changes in it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j58bv7tc/6/
i added function drawMeasure() for redraw line back to image after zoom in and out.
after drag, i also want all lines back. but i am confused in which event i need to add function drawMeasure().

Comment: Hi @bhaktiparmar, you can see the changes in this link. 
https://jsfiddle.net/48h31boe/3/

Comment: Thank you so much. sorry for my unstructured code. thank you for solution.

Comment: but for zoom in and zoom out, it will not work after much zoom as not at correct coordinates.

Comment: I need proper requirement as  I can see there translate point... why you need that also you can which is your origin point in canvas ? Is it top left or bottom left ?? I have shared my no. Or you can mail me at spankajd@gmail.com

Comment: Final solution : https://jsfiddle.net/tgbr2nxm/ from @spankajd

thank you so much sir!